# Segue not performing

Tags: iphone, ios, segue

I'm currently facing something I find rather strange.
In my storyboard, there is a TableViewController filled with static cells.

I would like to perform a simple segue (a push to another view controller) when I select one of the rows. 
So I "ControlDrag" from the concerned table cell to the sibling controller, but when tap one the cell, nothing happens. Next to that, I did try assigning the segue triggering to the accessory view of the cell (a disclosure button). And in that case, the segue is effectively triggered.

So here is my question : Should I use the "programmatic way" to handle the tap on the cell (tableview delegate methods and manual segue performing), or is there something I'm missing in the interface builder? And btw how could we explain the behavior difference with the accessory button view ?

Here is two screenshot

- Cell selection that should trigger segue

  [image: Cell selection that should trigger segue]

  And, the accessory action which performs the segue

  [image: accessory action]

Comment: Have you got some examples of what you tried? pictures / code

Comment: I'm going to add two pictures to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what the problem was. I had a gesture recognizer attached to the view controller, and it was catching the tap event on the cell.

Comment: I was just about to suggest that, I've had a similar problem that took nearly a week to solve.  If you want to use the recognizer and the segue in tandem, you can set the recognizer's `cancelsTouchInView` to false and they will both work.